# Ext.Ajax.request sending OPTIONS request cross-domain when jQuery.ajax sends GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha Touch application calling my web service cross-domain using Ext.Ajax.request. As I have built the web service I've enabled it to access cross-domain requests. However Ext sends an OPTIONS request first as a handshake then a GET request whereas jQuery.ajax just sends a GET request. Due to circumstances outside my control the hosting provider doesn't support OPTIONS requests. At the moment I have resorted to using jQuery for ajax requests and Sencha Touch for the rest of the application. I don't really want to have to load the jQuery library just for this.

Can anyone shed some light on why Ext.Ajax sends an OPTIONS request and is there a way to make it just send a GET?

Thanks

Comment: my problem too ! any luck finding the solution ? @CL4NCY

Answer (score 11):

In the `Ext.Ajax.request` config, set `useDefaultXhrHeader` to false. This will prevent the extra OPTIONS request.

According to [the docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax):

> Set this to false to not send the default Xhr header (X-Requested-With) with every request. This should be set to false when making CORS (cross-domain) requests.

My experience is that the OPTIONS call disappeared, I got the POST verb I expected.

Answer (score 5):

**Set**

`Ext.Ajax.useDefaultXhrHeader = false`

**Before**

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'www.yourUrl.com',
        .....
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can set with method like this :

```
Ext.Ajax.setUseDefaultXhrHeader(false);
Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: "http://yoururl.domain",
                    success: function(response, eOpt) {
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    failure: function(response, eOpt) {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                });
```